# Can we manage multiple screens with one Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

I just want to know how can  we manage multiple screens using a single  activity or do we need to create a different activity for each screen.Any help in this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setContentsView()` with different layouts from the same activity thus you can even change layouts on the fly. You can pass an extra within  the activity's launching intent and then choose a layout in your, say, onCreate() depending on that extra value.
But probably better different activities for different screens unless the changes to the UI anf logic are small

Comment: The setContentsView may cause problems when the activity is restored because some widgets may not be present.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a setContentsView method in the SDK/API.

Comment: @dpk the actual method is `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1):

You should create a different activity for each screen if it is a full screen view. This is good because it breaks up functionality and makes your code more modular. If you really want to have one activity with multiple screens controlled by it you have three options.

1. Use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and a [fragment activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) if you are using the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) or just a regular activity if you are targeting 3.0 or up to manage multiple fragments.
2. Have one activity with multiple views and just change the view when you would want to switch screens.
3. Use an [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) (deprecated) to launch multiple activities controlled by a single activity.

Comment: I think this is for one screen(Monitor). But you are talking about multi-window.